# How the C# compiler treats query expressions ?(Dotnet 3.5, C#3.0)

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, compiler-construction, c#-3.0

Going thru one of my favourite authors question [What’s the hardest or most misunderstood aspect of LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215548/whats-the-hardest-or-most-misunderstood-aspect-of-linq) I am basically looking for the answer of the question:

> How the C# compiler treats query expressions

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit broad of a question. In terms of what exactly? Or do you mean what do they end up being compiled as?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will evaluate and transform your query expressions into the equivalent lambda syntax before compiling the code further. So code that starts as

```
 var query = from foo in foos 
             where foo.Bar == someString
             select new 
             {
                 Baz = foo.Baz,
                 Id = foo.Id
             };
```

Will be transformed into the lambda version

```
 var query = foos.Where(f => f.Bar == someString).Select(f => new { Baz = f.Baz, Id = f.Id });
```

The same will happen to your complicated joins, groupings, etc.

Comment: But that's only half of the story, isn't it? The other half (at least for L2S) would be the transformation from lamba expression syntax to expression trees.

Comment: That other half would then be "how the C# compiler treats lambda expressions." I'll admit to really only thinking about this from a L2Objs perspective, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may vary between underlying LINQ providers.

Generally speaking, LINQ query expressions or method chains are transformed into Expression Tree before it goes to provider-specific implementation.

As for LINQ to Objects (IEnumerable), the expression tree is complied into a set of System.Func or System.Action delegates.

As for LINQ to SQL (IQueryable), the expression tree is transformed into T-SQL Statements.