# Understanding linq thoroughly

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I was just looking through this stack overflow question: [What's the hardest or most misunderstood aspect of LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215548/whats-the-hardest-or-most-misunderstood-aspect-of-linq) and I couldnt believe I was using so many of  these concepts sometimes correctly and sometimes incorrectly.

Can you guys please direct me to a book/blog that explains all these concepts. It would be really cool to understand all the details

Thanks in advance

Comment: As many have stated below, EduLINQ is the best source we have found over here for learning the ins and outs of Linq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read Jon Skeet's [EduLINQ series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).
Note: ***Long***

Answer (score 3):

Try [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series of articles.

Jon implements the whole of LINQ-to-Objects along with a series of explanatory blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Double thumbs up for Jon Skeet's Edulinq series :) Read this article [LINQ Secrets Revealed: Chaining and Debugging](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/). Also check [LINQ in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169) and [LINQ Pocket Reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596519254.do) books. Cheers!