# Interesting behavior : LINQ query with integer

Tags: c#, linq

If I use any integer variable in a LINQ `where` clause, and after query execution if I modify / initialize the integer variable, then the result set of the LINQ query changes. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
     int startPos = 0;          
     List<string> intList = new List<string>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        intList.Add(i.ToString());
     }

     var qResult = from c in intList
                   where Convert.ToInt32(c) >= startPos
                   select c;

     // prints count as 10
     Console.WriteLine("List count is :"+qResult.Count());

     startPos = 5;

     // prints count as 5
     Console.WriteLine("List count is :" + qResult.Count());
}
```

Output:

```
List count is :10
List count is :5
```

In above example you can see that after `startPos = 5;`, the `qResult` has changed. I don't understand how this has happened; as far as I know, `int` is value type.

Is the Linq query again executed at line `startPos = 5;`? If yes, then will it be a performance impact? And most importantly, am I missing anything here?

Comment: Deffered execution :) just use `.ToList()` to prevent it. Query is executed while geting data, not when writing `Where` clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq), [How does the following LINQ statement work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699877/how-does-the-following-linq-statement-work?newsletter=1&nlcode=180091%7cb8fe) and many others.

Comment: You should read up on closures: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). They're pretty neat once you understand them.

Comment: Just like wudzik stated this is deffered exeuction. In other words, this is normal behavior. When you make a query it is *not* executed. Only when you actually need data is will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

`qResult` is *enumerated* every time you call `.Count()`, so when you change `startPos` in between calls to `.Count()`, you are really changing the code being executed.

To avoid this, enumerate your list once by calling `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, or similar:

```
List<string> qResult = (from c in intList
                   where Convert.ToInt32(c) >=startPos
                   select c).ToList();
```

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) is a very good article on deferred execution in LINQ.

Comment: no sql involved in the example

Comment: @Chips_100 Good point, updated answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `qResult` will be an `IEnumerable<T>` and executed each time you call `.Count()`. If you want the result to never change simply use `ToList()` like this:

```
var qResult = (from c in intList
               where Convert.ToInt32(c) >=startPos
               select c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

.Count() does an enumeration when invoked. it is not like a variable value, so the result is consistent with the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The linq query is executed at the time of call since it use lazy loading, in your case your query is executed in `qResult.Count()`, if you wish to force the execution call `ToList()`, or similar function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because the `qResult` is Enumerated each time you call `Count()` and you are accessing a *modified [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx)* into the linq query. You should use a third variable to avoid this behavior:

```
        int pos = startPos;
        var qResult = from c in intList
                      where Convert.ToInt32(c) >= pos
                      select c;
```

or enumerate in place:

```
        var qResult = (from c in intList
                      where Convert.ToInt32(c) >= startPos
                      select c).ToArray();
```

It is called deffered execution