# Generic Get method does not include FK's?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, repository

I'm trying to create a generic GetAll method that works for each of my model classes in my ASP.NET MVC4 project.

Here's my code:

```
public static List<T> GetAll(params string[] includeProperties)
{
    using (MovieSiteDb db = new MovieSiteDb())
    {
        var entities = db.Set<T>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            entities.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return entities.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now I call it the following way (Movie inherits the GetAll method):

```
Movie.GetAll("Category");
```

However I get an error when I try to access the foreign key "Category" in the view model.
Why isn't it being included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a chunk of my generic repository with an `AllIncluding` method that can be called with lambda expressions

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

protected MyContext Context { get { return Uow.Context; } }

protected IUnitOfWork Uow
{
    get { return _UnitOfWork; }
}

public RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> All
{
    get
    {
        return Context.Set<T>();
    }
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T
                                          , object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = All;
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    //string sql = query.ToString();
    return query;
}
```

Here's an example how I call it from my Controller:

```
   IRepository<Answer> repo = _Uow.AnswerRepository;
   IOrderedQueryable<Answer> answers = repo.AllIncluding(answer => answer.Questions)
                                        .OrderBy(answer => answer.SortOrder)
                                        .ThenBy(answer => answer.Text);
```

Getting into units of work and other stuff here tho'

Comment: This might be a dumb question but could you give me an example as how to call this?
I tried:
AllIncluding(m => m.MovieCategory); But that gives me an error.

Comment: That should work. What error are you getting. I've included an example of how I use it

Comment: I'm getting the error:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MovieSite.Models.Movie,object>>[]' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I think it's something to do with the fact that I have chosen to return IQueryable<T> from my repository. One of the hardest or misunderstood aspects of LINQ  http://stackoverflow.com/a/215580/150342 ;-)

Comment: I see - I guess I'll do some more research

Comment: After a few attempts I got your example to work in my project - I don't know what I did wrong but thanks a lot - it works great now!

Answer (score 6):

I can't say I've used EF myself, but in general LINQ doesn't mutate queries when you call a method - instead it returns a new query. So if you change your code to:

```
DbQuery<T> entities = db.Set<T>();
foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
{
    entities = entities.Include(includeProperty);
}
```

you may find that fixes the problem.

(The type of `entities` is now fixed to `DbQuery<T>` rather than using `var` to implicitly type it to `DbSet<T>`, as `Include` returns `DbQuery<T>`.)

Comment: should not we use lambda expression with include method??

Comment: may be silly question sorry i am new in this field!!

Comment: Ahh yes of course - that makes sense.
By the way I've heard I could use lambda instead of strings - do you know how this would work?
If not I'll just mark this as the answer since it solved my initial problem - thanks.

Comment: In addition you'll need to drop the `var` and use  `DbQuery<T> entities = ...`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thanks, I wasn't sure about that. Will add it.

Answer (score 0):

for ur concern about lambda expression what i know it u can do below

```
var prodcutmasters = this.db.ProdcutMasters.Include(p => p.CategoriesMaster);
return (prodcutmasters.ToList());
```