# List order changes after modifying a property

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have the following code:

```
                // Order a list
                var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.name);

                // Take few elements to another list (copies as reference)
                List<GameObject> myList2 = orderedList.Where(x => x.z == y).ToList();

                // Rename the objects in myList2
                foreach(stuff in myList2)
                {
                    stuff.name = "Renamed";
                }
```

The question is why after modifying a property of an object in the myList2 changes the order of orderedList?

For example if the ordered list was *"a,b,c,d"* and I took the "*b*" and "*c*" to myList2. Then the orderedList would be "*a,d,Renamed,Renamed"* instead of "*a,Renamed, Renamed, d*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `orderedList` is not a *list*, but a *query*.

Everytime you iterate over `orderedList`, `OrderBy` is invoked *again*. This is called [*deferred execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215562/142637).

---

You can stop that behaviour by materializing the query, like

```
var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

This way, changing the elements in `orderedList` will not actually changed the ordering of the items inside `orderedList`.

If `myList` is already a `List<>`, you could of course sort the list in-place instead of creating another one, like

```
// Order a list; don't create a new one
myList.Sort((a, b) => a.name.CompareTo(b.name));
```

Comment: In my case order of the list is changing seldom for same parameters. I am wondering why? Order should be same each time a piece of code is executed for same inputs in my linq where clause? Or is there any thing special they way items are sort when using ToList() ? whats the consideration of default sorting when using ToList()?

Comment: even though I changed my where clause to convert into List via ToList() but order is still changing.